# How can users install fully unsigned (non-Apple) operating system on an Apple Silicon Mac?

Tags: startup, apple-silicon

The man page for `bputil` contains a somewhat-cryptic description of the `--permissive-security` setting:

> At a high level, ***Permissive Security allows configuration options to be set to not require all software to be digitally signed.*** This can allow users who are not part of the Apple Developer program to still be able to introduce their own software into their system. Additionally, especially dangerous security downgrades may be restricted to Permissive Security, and only available via CLI tools for power users rather than GUIs.

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/RwcT8stYMY/

Emphasis added.

Because `bputil` is for controlling the Boot Policy, I assume that "software" is referring to *bootable* software—ie, Operating Systems—rather than userspace macOS apps.

But, Apple is being more than a little cryptic! It doesn't say that "permissive security allows unsigned software", it says "Permissive Security *allows configuration options to be set*" to allow unsigned software! The configuration options themselves are notably absent.

What, precisely, would a user have to do to boot a non-Apple, not digital signed, and (let's say for the sake of argument) potentially-insecure operating system on an Apple Silicon Mac?

Comment: Unless you are a developer with one of the special developer-only Apple Silicon Macs it might be a bit early to expect an authoritative answer to that question before there are a lot of them sold and in the hands of the general public. Ans you seem to be learning Apple's documentation is often cryptic and couched in phrases that could mean a *lot* of things. But once the general public gets their hands on them expect that to change...

Comment: Thanks for posting the full man page for people not on Big Sur. In the context of that page, the "I assume that "software" is referring to bootable software—ie, Operating Systems—rather than userspace macOS apps" interpretation seems unlikely.

Comment: https://twitter.com/never_released/status/1326315741080150016 Is a start but not a full answer